# EZXML C Parsing API

Tags: c, api, xml-parsing

Can I use ezxml_get function this way to count the number of child **book** tags inside parent tag **books**? If child tag is not found, function returns NULL.

```
int books_cnt = 0;
     for(i=0; i<100; i++)
     {
     if((ezxml_get(xml_file, "books", 0, "book", i) != NULL)
         {
            books_cnt++;
         }
     }
```

This is how xml looks like

```
   <books>
        <book>
        </book>
        <book>
        </book>
         .
         .
         .
         .
   </books>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Didn't you try? Having a quick look on the [ezxml page](http://ezxml.sourceforge.net/), using `ezxml_child()` and looping through the linked list while counting yourself is probably much better (in terms of performance)

**[edit]** to completely clarify ... the website gives this example code:

```
for (team = ezxml_child(f1, "team"); team; team = team->next) {
    teamname = ezxml_attr(team, "name");
    for (driver = ezxml_child(team, "driver"); driver; driver = driver->next) {
        printf("%s, %s: %s\n", ezxml_child(driver, "name")->txt, teamname,
               ezxml_child(driver, "points")->txt);
    }
}
```

So just use something like the outer loop and count, e.g.:

```
int i = 0;
for (book = ezxml_child(xml_file, "book"); book; book = book->next) ++i;
```

Comment: but with ezxml_child() i will not get what I need, it will just return me first child tag with the given name or NULL if not found

Comment: and a `next` pointer to the next child, according to the website. It's just a linked list. Loop through the `next` pointers and count!

Comment: So with this code you wrote, what happens  with for loop if ->next is NULL?

Comment: the *loop condition* (second part in `for`) is just `book`. This evaluates to `false` in a boolean context if the pointer is `NULL`.

Comment: So you say that this for loop starts from first book tag he gets from ezxml_child, and goes through linked list searching for same that tag, always incrementing with next, when next is null it doesn't look like book we searching for and for loop stops? But what happens if we have for example <library><books><book></book><book></book><book></book><book></book> .... </books></library> Like this structure?